# Adding unnecessary files when executing the "npm i" command within the code

Tags: node.js, npm, exec

I have 4 projects that depend on each other, 3 nodes servers, and 1 react project.
I would like to write a little script called 'go.js' on an external server that runs the "npm i" commands for all of my projects, one after the other.

I built the following code in node to test one project (this is the go.js code):

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('npm i --prefix C:\\Or\\_OSREnterprises\\Web\\OSRWebVisualizer\\WebVisualizer\\streamer\\', {}, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(error);
    console.log(stdout);
    console.log(stderr);
  // work with result
});
```

and the output that i get:

```
> manager@1.0.0 go C:\Or\_OSREnterprises\Web\OSRWebVisualizer\WebVisualizer\manager
> node src/scripts/go.js

null
C:\Or\_OSREnterprises\Web\OSRWebVisualizer\WebVisualizer\streamer\parser -> C:\Or\_OSREnterprises\Web\OSRWebVisualizer\WebVisualizer\streamer\node_modules\@babel\parser\bin\babel-parser.js
C:\Or\_OSREnterprises\Web\OSRWebVisualizer\WebVisualizer\streamer\jsesc -> C:\Or\_OSREnterprises\Web\OSRWebVisualizer\WebVisualizer\streamer\node_modules\jsesc\bin\jsesc
C:\Or\_OSREnterprises\Web\OSRWebVisualizer\WebVisualizer\streamer\mime -> C:\Or\_OSREnterprises\Web\OSRWebVisualizer\WebVisualizer\streamer\node_modules\mime\cli.js
+ manager@1.0.0
added 107 packages from 102 contributors and updated 1 package in 7.807s
```

and when I go to the "streamer" folder, I see that the "node_modules" folders is there, but the node added some weird and unnecessary files:
[image]

Is there any way to avoid adding those files?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code to:

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec(command, {
                    cwd: applicationPath
                }, (error, stdout, stderr) => {

                    resolve({
                        error: error,
                        stdout: stdout,
                        stderr: stderr
                    });
                });
```

And it works without creating files.